# can not create virtual environment for a django project

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a Django project from scratch.
I executed `django-admin startproject autoshine` in my zsh terminal.
Then I opened pycharm and run `pipenv install` in its local terminal to create a virtual environment for this project. But I got this error:

```
 raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
```

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/mohsen/.local/share/virtualenvs/autoshine-YDp111VE/bin/python'`

I realized that in the above directory, it can create a virtual environment but unfortunately it doesn't have any bin file.
I don't know how to solve this problem.
Thank you for your answers in advance.

Comment: There was probably an earlier error message that explains why it was unable to create the virtual environment properly.

Answer (score 1):

PS `C:\Users\ADMIN`:

```
source/myenv/bin/activate
source/myenv/bin/activate
```

The term `source/myenv/bin/activate` is not recognized as the name of a `cmdlet`, function, script file, or operable program. *Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again*.

```
At line:1 char:1
+ source/myenv/bin/activate
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (source/myenv/bin/activate:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the default way of creating a venv. For more information look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html)

```
python3 -m venv tutorial-env
```

and activate it with

```
source/tutorial-env/bin/activate
```

Comment: Thank you my friend. The problem is that virtualenv cannot create the bin file to be used as source. I ran `virtualenv myenv` but it didn't work and couldn't create the bin file.

Comment: are you using linux or windows?

Comment: Ubuntu Linux.
I did what you said and it worked. Thank you